# Авторизация через Ldap в Symfony: Invalid credentials

Tags: symfony3

Настроил все по документации, но к сожалению при отправке запроса возвращает на страницу авторизации с сообщением Invalid credentials.
Делал все по документации.
uid_key - по умолчанию в AD sAMAccountName
security:

```
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#b-configuring-how-users-are-loaded
providers:
    my_ldap:
        ldap:
            service: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap
            base_dn: 'dc=example,dc=com'
            search_dn: 'dc=example,dc=com'
            search_password: 'password'
            default_roles: ROLE_USER
firewalls:
    # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    main:
        anonymous: ~
        form_login_ldap:
            login_path: login
            check_path: login
            service: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap
            dn_string: '{username},dc=example,dc=com'

#         $someArgument: 'some_value'
Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap:
    arguments: ['@Symfony\Component\Ldap\Adapter\ExtLdap\Adapter']
Symfony\Component\Ldap\Adapter\ExtLdap\Adapter:
    arguments:
        -   host: 1*.**.**.**
            options:
                protocol_version: 3
                referrals: false
```

Answer (score 1):

- Параметр `search_dn` должен содержать полный путь до пользователя с правами только для чтения (через которого будет осуществляться поиск) в каталоге LDAP. Например: **CN=search_username,CN=Users,DC=example,DC=com**
- Параметр `search_password` - пароль пользователя search_username
- Параметр `dn_string` должен быть вида **{username}@example.com**

Comment: я пробовал все варианты, но к сожалению не работает, я даже могу вам логи показать. А так же можете посмотреть там есть логи [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49273563/symfony-3-4-ldap-authentication-issue] (вторая ссылка на английскую версию)

Comment: Смотрю по ссылке - там в `search_dn` указан юнит *OU=all-users-accounts,DC=example,DC=com* - а здесь надо указывать конкретного пользователя (не который логинится) у которого есть права на поиск в ldap

Comment: Я попробовал но не в какую не срабатывает, та же ошибка. Попробовал просто проверить вроде получаю ответ             echo "login successful";
$ldap = ldap_connect("**.**.**.**");

        if (ldap_bind($ldap, "turdubekuulu_a@example.com", "**********")) {
            echo "login successful";
        } else {
            echo "Incorrect Login";
        }

Comment: Если честно мне нужно просто ldap_bind и все, хочу проверить логин и пароль, но к сожалению он не работает. Так то я в обычном php реализовывал такое, но хотел в symfony его реализовать. И не получается. Как можно с вами связаться?)